# UIView 1px height always scales wrong in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder

I have a custom `Tableview` Cell in `Interfacebuilder`, this is how it looks in `IB`:

[image]

Notice the thin white line under the label. This is how it's supposed to look during runtime.

The hierarchy of the `UITableViewCell`:

[image]

My problem is, during runtime of the app, the line (which is the first `View` under the `View`) scales too big, I think to about 5px height, maybe even bigger.

I tried the following after some research, but it doesn't work.

```
cell.line.frame =CGRectMake(161,36,282,1/[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
```

Comment: What value does cell.line.frame actually have? Did you try `1.0f/[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]` ?

Comment: NSLog says the Rect has {{161, 36}, {282, 0.5}}, I tried 1.0f but it didnt work.

Comment: 0.5 should be fine. In that case the 1.0f is not required. I was not sure about what the result is, when an interger (1) is devided by a float (scale returns CGfloat).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should add height constrain to the line view.

Comment: Im trying arround a lot of things with constrains now. So far nothing seems to work.

Comment: after 10.000 years, I'm free. I had to add a height and width constraint. Thanks anyway.

Comment: if anyone has the same issue: Make sure to delete all the other constrains related to that view after you added the height constrains.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the line is configured to scale vertically. Make sure to turn that off in IB.

Comment: hmm sorry but I cant find where to toggle it off. Can you help me?

Comment: Looks like that setting is gone with the introduction of Auto Layout, sorry.